# Nested Analogies

Tags: language

Your puzzle is solving a nested analogy, where the goal is to find the word that fills in the final blank, based on the answer to the analogy in parentheses.

An example:

> sky:blue::(bird:worm::cow:____):____

In this case, the answer to the part in parentheses is "grass", which makes the whole thing:

> sky:blue::grass:____

So, the final answer is green.

Now, for the puzzle you must solve (which is not as straightforward as the example):

> wing:horn::(toodle-oo:hour::oboe:____):____

Comment: This is my first question on this site, so if anyone has any advice on formatting, difficulty, or the question itself, please let me know. Also, if it is too hard (I'm not really sure how difficult it will be for people on this site), just let me know, and I can provide more hints.

Comment: No need to include a hint immediately. The premise is interesting, though.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the hint for now, and I'll put it back later if necessary.

Comment: @Bonhomme For future reference, people can see revision history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also working from Gareth's partial answer of

> wing:horn :: wood:____

I think he was on the right track of

> another cross-language connection using the strong key of wing:horn = flugelhorn. Building on wood = *Holz*, there's a German stringed instrument called a *[scheitholz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheitholt)*; *Scheit* translates into "log" (or "piece," "chip," etc). However, it's a little strange that this name would reverse the clue's word order (i.e. to log:wood rather than wood:log). Digging deeper, there's also a *[holztrompete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holztrompete)* that's admittedly pretty obscure, but has some nice coincidences: word order is maintained, and an English cognate makes up its second half, much like flugelhorn. More subjectively, the wiki page mentions oboes (seen in the original clue); even more subjectively, I play the trumpet.

As such, I'd guess the answer is

> wing:horn :: wood:trumpet

Comment: Could very well be right. (I was just thinking the other day "hmm, I should revisit this one and do an exhaustive search for musical instruments whose German name begins with Holz". Looks like I should have done it :-).)

Comment: Admittedly, I had a different answer in mind, but this actually fits better than my answer, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**

It's conjectured that

> "toodle-oo" is a corruption of French "tout à l'heure".

Accordingly,

> since "oboe" = "haut bois", the inner analogy must yield "wood".

So now we have

> wing:horn :: wood:____

but I'm feeling dim and failing to see what that yields. Perhaps

> it's another cross-language thing? E.g., I think a wing in German is a *Flügel* and there is a musical instrument called a flugelhorn; but wood in german is *Holz* and all that leads me to is that woodwind in German is Holzblas, which would yield an answer of "blow". But that's, well, not terribly convincing.

Comment: You're right about the part in parentheses, but as you suspected, the final conjecture about Holzbas is not correct. Keep it up, you are very close!

Answer (score 4):

Using Gareth answer we have

> wing:horn :: wood:____

The relationship can be

> wings have feathers made of keratin (horn)

Answer:

> Cellulose (wood is made of cellulose)